# generating past months and joining unrelated data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In MySQL or MSSQL I need to generate a result set that will return the `qheader` grouped by month for the last three months. So I have the `questionsec` table schema

```
+-----------+
|questionsec|
+-----------+
|qid   (PK) |
|qheader    |
+-----------+
```

After

```
(select * from questionsec)
```

I get:

```
+-------+------+
|qid| qheader  |
+---|----------+
| 1 | QH1      |
| 2 | QH2      |
+---+----------+
```

What is the query I need to write to generate the following resultset:

```
+-------+---------+
|month  | qheader |
+-------|---------+
|2014-09| QH1     |
|2014-09| QH2     |
|2014-10| QH1     |
|2014-10| QH2     |
|2014-11| QH1     |
|2014-11| QH2     |
+-------+---------+
```

I know that the following will generate (in MySQL) the past three months but not sure how to join to each month row every `qheader` found in `questionsec`

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(now()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m') as month
UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now()- INTERVAL 2 MONTH,'%Y-%m')
UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now()- INTERVAL 3 MONTH,'%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Your solution will be easier and more scalable with a [Numbers Table](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creative-solutions-by-using-a-number-table/). Read up, then ask any questions if you are unsure how it solves your problem.

Comment: does you table have date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 CREATE TABLE questionsec(qid INT NOT NULL,qheader CHAR(3));

 INSERT INTO questionsec VALUES (1,'QH1'),(2,'QH2');

 SELECT qheader,month FROM questionsec x JOIN (SELECT '2014-09' month UNION SELECT '2014-10' UNION SELECT '2014-11')y;
 +---------+---------+
 | qheader | month   |
 +---------+---------+
 | QH1     | 2014-09 |
 | QH2     | 2014-09 |
 | QH1     | 2014-10 |
 | QH2     | 2014-10 |
 | QH1     | 2014-11 |
 | QH2     | 2014-11 |
 +---------+---------+
```